# Line between divs

Tags: html, css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I want to draw a line between `div`, but can't figure out how to make `<hr>` take the length of the main `div`

Maybe there is some other solution?

I use react and semantic ui comments

[image]

create comment block:

```
const CommentWithReply: FunctionComponent<ICommentProps> = ({ author, createdAt, text, replies }) => (
  <div className={styles.comment}>
    <BasicComment createdAt={createdAt} text={text} author={author} />
    <hr className={styles.hr}></hr>
    <div className="comments">
      {replies.map(e => (
        <CommentWithReply
          replies={e.comments}
          author={e.author}
          createdAt={e.createdAt}
          text={e.text}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Basic comment

```
const BasicComment: FunctionComponent<IBasicCommentProps> = ({ createdAt, text, author }) => (
  <div className={styles.commentInfo}>
    <div className={styles.commentAuthor}>
      <a href="/" className="avatar">
        <img alt="avatar" src="https://i.imgur.com/LaWyPZF.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="/" className="author">
        {author.lastName}
        {' '}
        {author.lastName}
      </a>
      <DividerSvg />
      <div className="metadata">
        <span className="date">{ moment(createdAt).fromNow() }</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="content">
      <div className="text">
        { text }
      </div>
      <div className="actions">
        <DarkBorderButton className={styles.btnReplay} content="Reply" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

styles.scss

```
.comment {
  margin-top: 1.25em;
  border: 2px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;

    &:only-child {
      &:last-child {
        .hr {
          visibility: visible;
          display: flex;
          width: 100%;
        }
        border: none;
      }
    }
  &:last-child {
    margin-bottom: -2em;
    .hr {
      display: none;
    }

    &:last-child {

    }
  }
}
```

main:

```
const CommentsFeed: FunctionComponent<ICommentProps> = ({ comments }) => (
  <div className={styles.main}>
    <p className={styles.commentCounter}> Discussion (58) </p>
    <form className="ui reply form">
      <div className="field">
        <textarea placeholder="Add to the discussion..." />
      </div>
      <DarkBorderButton className={styles.buttonSend} content="Send" />
    </form>
    <div className="ui comments">
      <div className="comment">
        {comments.map(comment => (
          <CommentWithReply
            createdAt={comment.createdAt}
            text={comment.text}
            author={comment.author}
            replies={comment.comments}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: why not use a `border-bottom`?

Comment: @tacoshy i tried, but they are also not from the edges of the red line. I need a line to be as long as the parent (first) comment

Comment: You can use `border-bottom`, you may need to change the CSS for the children comments, because you will run into the same problem using an `hr` element. Also, post the rendered HTML for the comment section. Your react code is not easy for us to help debug.

Comment: @disinfor how to make the line take the length from the first comment?

Comment: Post your rendered HTML and we can help.

Comment: @disinfor added as main. I just started learning react, it is possible that I made comments incorrect

Comment: I think last two `divs` which are not taking full width horizontal line because those are  `CommentWithReply`. So you need to check your CSS for `replied comments`.

Comment: If I am right, then wrap your `CommentWithReply` section with a `div` and use `border-bottom` with that div.

Comment: @Vadym that's your component code. What is the HTML that is rendered in the browser?